# how to set up a webpage with a transparent background for displaying data and a title

Tags: html, css, video-streaming, web-development-server

I am trying to recreate the poll results overlaid on a video as Grant Sanderson does in his videos [see here](https://youtu.be/MHXO86wKeDY?t=136). He mentions in his blog [here](https://www.3blue1brown.com/blog/livestream-setup#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20bars%20overlaid%20on%20the%20stream%2C%20we%20set%20up%20a%20webpage%20that%20displays%20the%20real%2Dtime%20updated%20bars%20and%20a%20title%20on%20a%20transparent%20background) that this is done by setting up "a webpage that displays the real-time updated bars and a title on a transparent background". I am setting up a simple html web page and I would like to know how to set up the webpage with a transparent background.

Specifically, I am looking for guidance on how to create a webpage that will display a webpage on a transparent background. I have tried using css and different browsers pluggings/extensions, but I am not sure how to make the background transparent.

Any suggestions or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The body element's background colour is changed to transparent with the `background-color: transparent` attribute, allowing the content to be seen through it. The CSS can be modified to meet your unique requirements.

Remember that the browser and the material displayed on the webpage will affect how transparent they are. It could be challenging to perceive the transparency effect if the background of the webpage's content is cluttered or bright.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>This is a transparent webpage</h1>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```